# create a sharepoint 2010 workflow to create a new list item from in intake form library to a assessment form library

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, workflow, infopath

I have an intake form ( in a form library) that once submitted kicks off a SharePoint designer (2010) work flow to create a new list item. It creates a new item in my 'assessment' form library.

Issue:  the workflow works - an item is created, but i have an error that my new item created cannot read the retrieve data connections that I have.  This new assessment form has information pulled in from external tables.

Is there a way to get this to work.  The goal would be to have Intake #1 submitted by the end user and then corresponding Assessment #1 created and the end user would go to that item and complete the information.

Comment: You might need an impersonation step to elevate the permissions of the action that is retrieving the data in the workflow.  If you can share more information about your workflow that would be helpful.

Comment: I've tried the impersonation step to elevate the permissions.  I'm getting the following error msg in regards to a list that i have as a secondary data connection (retrieve).

Comment: The query cannot be run for the following DataObject: EPP Customer Experience Scorecard Matrix
The SOAP response indicates that an error occurred on the server:

Comment: Exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException' was thrown.
<detail><errorstring xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">No item exists at http://w9.collaboration.td.com/projects/Lists/EPP%20Customer%20Experience%20Scorecard%20Matrix/.  It may have been deleted or renamed by another user.</errorstring><errorcode xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">0x80070002</errorcode></detail>